# layout_gravity is not working for my CirclePagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, viewpagerindicator

I want to set my `CirclePagerIndicator` to be in the left side. So I used this code in resource:
`android:layout_gravity = "left"` and I already knew that layout_gravity is working when the orientation of parent linear_layout is vertical, but the layout for my CirclePagerIndicator is in the `center`and `not left`. This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/priority_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="80sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallInverse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/BLACK" />

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_gravity = "left" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/time_reporting_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:src="@drawable/clock"
                android:text="@string/time_reporting" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="6dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the LinearLayout where your CirclePageIndicator is set, the gravity property is working but on its left you have placed a RelativeLayout, so it's normal that your CirclePageIndicator can't be at the left side because there is alredy a RelativeLayout there. I don't know if you were asking for this, if not, explain better please

Comment: Yes, but then the CirclePageIndicator should be come to the left side of it's linear layout. (right side of relative layout) That's the problem. It becomes center in it's linear layout.

Comment: I've tried your layout and it works for me. It is placed on the left of its linearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the CirclePageIndicator is as far left as it can be.  It is just to the right of the ViewPager that is laid out before it in the horizontally oriented LinearLayout that is grand-parent to both.

You should probably have a look at this layout in the lint tool.  You could probably clean it up a lot...

Answer (score 0):

```
   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    :::::::::::
    :::::::::::
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    :::::::::::
    ::::::::::: />
```